# Run python script and display printed value on a website

Tags: javascript, python, plc

I have a Python script that prints the current value that is being sent from a PLC connected on the same network as my PC.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#fetchVar.py argument-with-plc-variable-name
#some script to connect to PLC and fetch
#current value of variable sent as argument
print plcVar
```

The script works - meaning every time I run this script I got printed the updated value of the variable I want. Example:

> python fetchVar.py aiTemperature
>
> 15

That means, the current value in PLC of variable named "aiTemperature" is 15.
I'm trying to display the printed temperature in a HTML page, this is what I got so far:

```
<body onload="varupdate()">
    <script language="JavaScript">
        var int=self.setInterval("varupdate()",2000); // update Temperature every two seconds
        
        function varupdate() {
            // somehow run "python fetchVar.py aiTemperature"
            var x = ????;       //The printed value from getVar.py should be saved here
            document.getElementById("var1").innerHTML="Current Temperature = " + x;
        }
    </script>
    <div id="var1"></div>
</body>
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: how difficult would it be to rewrite your function in javascript? are there dependencies that require that you use python?

Comment: It depends on which plc I use. In my case I use Wago - for which it could work (a javascript - only solution). But other PLCs can only communicate via Modbus Tcp or serial comm, which force you to use Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to enable your server to run .py files (keyword: cgi-bin), then upload your .py file to your cgi-bin folder (Hint for Windows Users: save all your files with "Linux/Unix Format" - On npp go to Edit/EOL Conversion/Linux Format).

On the HTML I have:

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function ReadTemperature() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://my-server/cgi-bin/fetchVar.py",
            type: "post",
            datatype: "html",
            data: {
                webArguments: "aiTemperature" //Arguments you want to send to your .py
            },
            success: function(response){
                    $("#aiTemperature").html(response);
            },
            complete: function() {
                setTimeout(ReadTemperature, 2000);   //Refresh value every 2 seconds
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Current temperature: <div id="aiTemperature"></div> °C.</p>
</body>
```

On the Python file, you need to add the addressing of "webArguments" to "Python Arguments"... In my case i had to add the following to my "normal" script:

```
import cgi, cgitb
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"    #for showing print on HTML
data = cgi.FieldStorage()
argument = data["webArguments"].value    #argument = name of PLC i need to fetch
#some script for connecting to PLC and reading current value of 
#variable  with name "argument", in this example "aiTemperature"
print plcVar
```

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to make your python script answer get requests using an [HTTP request handler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html). Then you would have to send a request in [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) within your JavaScript file to get the value you want.

It might take a bit of work, but it is well documented and you should learn quite a bit doing this.